# React.js element jumps up and down by drag and drop

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement drag and droip function in react js. For this I use `mousemove`, `mouseUp` and `mouseDown`. With  `useRef` I have a reference to the element I want to move. With the reference I can set the offset of top and left and with pageX and pageY I can set the new position of the element.

However, I have the problem that when I move the element, the offset of top and left varies by about 30 pixels. As a result, when moving the element, the element jumps back and forth. Here is my code

App.jsx

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import User from './User'
import './App.css'

function App() {

  const [isSeatEmpty, setIsSeatEmpty] = useState([]);
  const [userProps, setUserProps] = useState({
    index: 0,
    backgroundColor: "gray",
    userSize: 100,
    xPosition: 0,
    yPosition: 0,
  })

  const [userList, setUserList] = ([]);


  function setEmptySeats() {
    const maxSeats = 20;
    let tempArray = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < maxSeats; index++) {

      if (index != 17) {
        tempArray.push({
          seat: index,
          empty: true
        });
      }
      else {
        tempArray.push({
          seat: index,
          empty: false
        });
      }
    }

    setIsSeatEmpty(tempArray);
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    setEmptySeats();

  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <User props={userProps}/>

    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

App.css

```
#root{
  margin:auto;
}

.container{
  border:1px solid black;
  height:50vh;
  width:50vw;
  position:'relative'
}
```

User.jsx

```
import { React, useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import './User.css'

function User(props) {

    const [user, setUser] = useState({});

    const [isMousePressed, setIsMousePressed] = useState(false);
    const refToUser = useRef();

    function moveUser(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let xOffset = refToUser.current.offsetLeft;
        let yOffset = refToUser.current.offsetTop;

        if (isMousePressed) {

            refToUser.current.style.top = `${e.pageY-yOffset}px`;
            refToUser.current.style.left = `${e.pageX - xOffset}px`
            console.log("x: " + e.pageX +" " +xOffset + " y: " + e.pageY + " " + yOffset )

        }
        //console.log(isMousePressed);
    }

    function mousePressed(e) {
        setIsMousePressed(true);
        console.log("pressed");
    }

    function mouseReleased(e) {
        setIsMousePressed(false);
        console.log("released");
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(user);
    }, [user])

    useEffect(() => {

        setUser({
            ...user,
            name: "",
            height: props.props.userSize,
            width: props.props.userSize,
            backgroundColor: props.props.backgroundColor
        })
    },[])

    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{
                height: user.height,
                width: user.width,
                position: "relative",
                backgroundColor: "gray"
            }}
                onMouseMove={moveUser}
                onMouseDown={mousePressed}
                onMouseUp={mouseReleased}
                ref={refToUser}
                ></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default User
```

I tried to restructure the code because I thought it was the rendering. Likewise, I also set `position` to absolute because I thought that might be the problem.

Otherwise I have no idea why the offset of top and left varies.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to save the position of the mouse in the mousedown function. Instead of calculating with the offset of top, the new position of the element must be calculated with the mouse position.

The video helped me out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcDWyVj6-uU&t=1s&ab_channel=DiveinDev